# What is the best way to setup my "main" for a class library?

Tags: c#, dll, class-library

Okay so I'm trying to create an class library for an existing game.
I'm stuck with a problem though I'd like to clear up and have done properly.

So let's say I've got my Class library in the namespace Api
This api contains multiple classes for example: Memory, Client, Player, Keyboard

Now I don't want the person using this Api to have to initialize everything personally.

I came up with the solution to use an extra class containing the initialized instances for the other classes so the user can do the following

```
using Api

Api.API MyGame = new Api.API();
```

And then having the API class be something like this:

```
public class API {
    public Player player;
    public Client client;

    public API(){
        Player = new Player();
        Client = new Client();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is a correct way of doing or if I'm totally in the wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using Dependecy Injection / Inversion of Control:

- [Autofac](http://www.autofac.org) for registering (there are several others, such as Ninject, etc)
- [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) for assembly discovery (using export and imports)